# I want to create a popup

Tags: java, android, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a popup.

I would like to make the background of my popup transparent, and the border, because the popup is not filling the page, a bit more opaque, is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried with an activity but i can't get the effect i want, can you help me?

Something like this:
[image: something like this]

Comment: Read the documentation carefully- https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Alert Dialogs for this and check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) for different uses

And a simple one like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog Title");
        builder.setMessage("Your Message");
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUadH.png)

Comment: thanks, this is much better than mine, and i think that with some edit it will be what i need